# ANOVA/ANCOVA results in SPSS

Tags: anova, interaction, spss, ancova, controlling-for-a-variable

I am unsure about how to interpret the output box I get doing an ANOVA in SPSS. That's the "Tests of between-subject effects" box in particular. I had 2 groups (A and B), and 2 results (EnergykJT0 and EnergykJT1).

**I used the following inputs for my model**:

- EnergykJT1 as my dependent variable.
- Groups as a fixed variable.
- EnergykJT0 as a covariate.

**In the output box, I get these listed values**:

- Corrected model
- Intercept
- Group
- EnergykJT0

All are accompanied by their significance value. I am trying to identify which corresponds to time, the interaction, and treatment. My best guess is group = treatment, and the covariate = interaction? Don't know about time. I haven't worked with ANCOVA before. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste in your actual results?  That would help.  Also, you say ANOVA in your title and ANCOVA in your text.

Comment: Oh buger, yes, I mean ANCOVA. This is what I got when I ran it: I can't paste it in here so I have to key it in. I suppose the column which matter are the source and the sig. So that's what I got: corrected model <0.001, intercept 0.007, group 0.025, energykJT0 <0.01.

Comment: There should be SOME way to paste it in. There usually is. But I don't know SPSS very well, so I don't know how. Can SPSS write output to some other sort of file?

Comment: Screenshot and use the image?

Comment: Is this a repeated measures version? I saw you only briefly mention time here. Also agree that screenshotting and pasting the image would be helpful.

Comment: SPSS (at least latest versions') default for ANCOVA is to just give you the main effects of group and covariate, so unless you used model dialogue box's custom term bulding options I doubt you have an interaction in your output. The values you have in your between-subjects effects output in the row with your covariate's name probably refer to the main effect of said covariate. SPSS shows interaction in output as group*covariate.

Comment: But you should at least clarify if you are using repeated-measures ANCOVA or not. For repeated measures, SPSS (again at least latest versions) does give you the interactions between time and other predictors as default (but not interactions between predictors other than time).

Answer (score 0):

It's still difficult to say what you have as you didn't post a screenshot of your output, but it seems you have measured something ("Energy"?) at two time points, pre- and post treatment and you want to know whether the Energy scores change, and whether they change differently in the two groups, right?

I'm fairly sure in your current analysis you have used a between-subject ANCOVA with one covariate without specifying any interactions or including an effect of time. So, in your current model, you are using your baseline (first) time point measure of energy as the covariate and your second time point measurement as your outcome. This is fine for pre-post data if you're primarily interested in the different treatment groups' means post treatment and not whether there are differences in pre-post change. If you choose this way, you don't need to add the interaction between treatment and covariate. You can just report whether the two treatment group means differ from each other.

Another common way to analyze data like this is repeated measures ANOVA with time * group interaction*. In SPSS, this is done differently from all other software I've used; the data is kept in short format (i.e. you have only one row per participant and one column for pre-treatment score and another for post-treatment score) and you don't have a separate "time" variable. You need to go to the General Linear Model...Repeated Measures menu. Then, you enter the pre and post score of your dependent variable (Energy) into the "within-subjects factor" dialogue box. Then you click "Define" and put your treatment group variable into the between-subjects factors box. This analysis has the within-subjects (i.e., here, the pre-post) and between-subjects factor (here, the treatment group, A vs. B) interaction added as default. This analysis is better if you are interested in possible group difference in *change* between the two time points. The interaction tells you whether there are differences in change between the two groups.

In any case, I'd recommend you plot your raw Energy data points from pre and post time points separately for each treatment group (I'd put pre vs. post in the x-axis and have separate lines for each treatment group). This will give you a clearer idea of what happens in your data.

*(or a multilevel regression with participant id as random effect, which would be more or less equivalent to RM-ANOVA in this case)